# Python Regex : Get data after second underscore?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get data after second underscore?

sample:

```
abc_def 1223_this_6729

abc_def,1223_this_6729

abc_def1223_this_6729
```

output

```
this_6729
```

Comment: split  & join should work ```"_".join("abc_def1223_this_6729".split("_")[2:])```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data ***after*** the second underscore (as per question) you can set the maxsplit parameter of `split` function to 2:

```
str = 'abc_def 1223_this_6729'
str.split('_',2)[2]
```

Returns:

```
this_6729
```

Since the returned array is zero-based `[2]` will get the remainder of your string after two underscores.

Answer (score 0):

With the very simple examples in mind, this will do the trick:

```
re.search("_(\w+_\d+$)", "abc_def 1223_this_6729").group()
```